# Install apache2 on ubuntu 17.10

Tags: ubuntu, apache2

I have problems installing apache2, it does not start, and I can to see

Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: 
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
           └─apache2-systemd.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code)

Comment: I suggest you to use nginx instead

Comment: I'm used to apache, I try to install lamp

Comment: I finished install xampp since apache.org